# Find an specific element in a MongoDB document from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to access MongoDB from C# ASP.NET application.

Let's assume, I've a document like below-

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546c776b3e23f5f2ebdd3b03"),
    "Name" : "Test",
    "Values" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "One",
            "Value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Two",
            "Value" : 2,
            "Parameters": [{"Type": "Type A"}, {"Type": "Type B"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that, only the `_id` and `Name` elements are fixed; other elements are dynamically created by the user where both the key and value are defined by the user.

Now,  I would like to search for the element `Type` with the value `Type A`. How can I do this from a MongoDB C# driver?

Comment: do you want to search Parameters.Type values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var query = Query.EQ("Values.Parameters.Type", "Type A");
var items = collection.Find(query).ToList();
```

If you data has structure use this:

```
var items = collection.FindAs<Item>(query).ToList();
```

**Edit:**
For dynaically search the only way comes to my mind is full-text-search:

**Step1:** Define a full text-search on all fields via `db.test.ensureIndex({"$**" : "text"});`

**Step2:** Search your query `db.test.find( { $text: { $search: "Type A" } } )`

If its your answer, the C# code should be easy.

Comment: "Values.Parameters" is dynamically defined by user. There may be more elements here i.e. "Values.Parameters.Element1.Element2" or "Values.Element1.Element2.Parameters". I'll only search "Type": "Type A". Is it possible?

Comment: What namespace do these functions(`FindAs<T>`, `Query`) come from?

Answer (score 0):

Below aggregation query may solve your problem but I don't know how to write this in C#

```
db.collectioName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$Values"},
         {"$unwind":"$Values.Parameters"},
        {"$match":{"Values.Parameters.Type":"Type A"}},
       {"$group":{"_id":"$Values"}})
```