# Unable to get Query class in MongoDb.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am referring this post 
[Find an specific element in a MongoDB document from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016837/find-an-specific-element-in-a-mongodb-document-from-c-sharp?rq=1)
to fetch the Element value from a specific document in MongoDB. But unable to find the Nuget MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update in my Project.Project is of type Class project.So Query class not recognized. I have installed the MongoDB.Driver - 2.4.0 Ver, MongoDB.Bson & MOngoDb.Driver.Core Nugets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the latest driver and use linq? The Query object isn't available in the latest driver. The post you are referring to is quite old.

See this answer which explains how to use Find, with and without Builders.

[MongoDB Find in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164908/mongodb-and-c-sharp-find/40171761#40171761)