# ASP.Net Core using MongoDB.Driver.Builder driver

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I've a Web Api project where I am trying to use Query Object from the MongoDB.Driver.Builder library, but I can't find this library.
I have installed MongoDB.Driver 2.4.0
My Web Api Project is ASPNetCore 2.0.0

There is a similar question here at Stackoverflow, though there is no solution only suggestion of using linq instead.
Please refer to this link: [Unable to get Query class in MongoDb.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554622/unable-to-get-query-class-in-mongodb-driver)

Which approach is more recommended and why can't I find this library?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe it's better to try to explain what kind of query you want to execute.. show us some code. There is a CreateQuery command on Driver.Builder: http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Query_Create.htm but it's hard to guess what you want with just that.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I can't find the mongodb.Driver.Builder library at all and that's my first problem. For the query I am trying to implement a Web Api project using Mongodb Indexing.

Comment: Why do you need the query object? what are you trying to query?

Comment: I have a Product collection, whereby I am trying to write some queries using the Query Class. Something like this, not sure if this line of code works as I am still missing this library so I can't access the Query object.  `IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("productName", "ProductA");
            var result = collection.Find(query).FirstAsyncOrDefault();`

Comment: @RHJ that's the pre-2.0 method of constructing queries. See Ryan Dobbs' answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the MongoDB.Driver 2.5 nuget package and I can see the Builders.

I have used them like this.

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

var filter = builder.Eq("_id",ObjectId.Parse(""));
```

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/driver/definitions/

Comment: Just to note, this exists in the `MongoDB.Driver` namespace, so a `using MongoDB.Driver;` directive is required.